# My while loop won't work even though player_strikes_left is > 0. Also the code below returns wrong values

Tags: python, while-loop

**Code:**

```
player_strikes_left = 3
player_score = 0

player_answer = input("player answer: ")
player_answer = player_answer.upper()

while player_strikes_left > 0:
    for item in possible_answers:
        points = item[1]
        is_correct = (player_answer in answer)
        if is_correct:
            print("true")
            player_score = player_score + points
        else:
            player_strikes_left -= 1

print(f'player score: {player_score}, player strikes left: {player_strikes_left}')
```

The problem with my code is that the while loop won't work even though the variable `player_strikes_left` is smaller than 0.

The output of the code is wrong, it supposed to return 2 as `player_strikes_left` but it returns -5. If the answer is correct the `player_strikes_left` variable should not change but it becomes -4 for some reason.

Comment: By wrong values, I meant that if the answer is wrong, it is supposed to do return 2 as player_strikes_left but it returns -5. If the answer is correct the player_strikes_left should not change but it becomes -4 for some reason and I cannot understand why

Comment: Please use code blocks to format your code; it's hard to read without proper indents/newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that you loop over the possible answer and decrement `player_strikes_left` for each possible answer instead of one time.